# AngularFire: What is the best practice to test if $firebaseObject has no keys?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Simple JavaScript object is empty (= has no keys) when `angular.equals({}, myObj) === true`.

Is there some utility function to detect if `$firebaseObject` has no keys? It will be never equal to `{}` because it looks like this:

```
{
   $$conf: Object,
   $id: "objectId",
   $priority: null,
   $value: null
}
```

EDIT: I am trying to hide `<div>` when `$firebaseObject` has no data. It seems like this do the trick but I don't know if it is the correct solution:

```
<div ng-hide="myObj.$value === null">

[...]

</div>
```

From [the doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html):

> If the value in the database is a primitive (boolean, string, or
>   number) then the value will be stored under this `$value` key. Modifying
>   this value and then calling `$save()` will also update the server’s
>   value.
>
> Note that any time other keys exist, this one will be ignored. To
>   change an object to a primitive value, delete the other keys and add
>   this key to the object.
>
> [...]

My `$firebaseObject` has children like this:

```
key: {
   value1: 'something',
   value2: 'something'
}
```

When I played around with `$value` I found this:

- When `$firebaseObject` has no child, `$value` is `null`
- When `$firebaseObject` has one child, `$value` is its key
- When `$firebaseObject` has more then one child, `$value` contains all the children objects

The question is, can I use `$value` this way to solve my problem or is it impossible because...?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you share what you're trying to accomplish and the code that you've tried?

Comment: Looks like the correct solution to me. Although I'd go for ng-show="myObj"

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen `ng-show="myObj"` doesn't work for me. Can you explain it more closely (write an answer maybe), please?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen [here](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/ojBNvg?editors=101) is demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is how you bind the data in the controller:

```
function MainController($firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com');
  vm.users = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users'));
```

This works for show/hide:

```
<div class="small-12 column" ng-show="vm.users">
  <h1>No user</h1>
</div>
<div class="small-12 column" ng-show="!vm.users">
  <h1>Users</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in vm.users">{{user}}</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Btw: since you're using `ng-repeat` over users, you'll want to make it a `$firebaseArray()`.

Comment: Oh, `ng-show="vm.users"` shows the `div` if `vm.users` has no data? Why? I would assume the opposite behaviour. Btw, it is working well with `$firebaseObject` - why is `$firebaseArray` better?

Comment: I didn't dig too deep, just updated it to what I do here: https://trenches.firebaseapp.com/